# No ReverseMatch URL django

Tags: django, templates, hyperlink, view, reverse

I have a scenario that looks like this:

Models

```
from django.db import models

from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy, reverse

class State(models.Model):
    short_name = models.CharField('Abbreviation', max_length=2)
    state = models.SlugField('State Name', max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.state

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('state_list', kwargs={'state': self.state})

class City(models.Model):
    state = models.ForeignKey(State)
    city = models.CharField('City', max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'City'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Cities'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.city

class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=69, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'School'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Schools'
```

Views

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView

from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

from .models import School, City, State

def reviews_index(request):
    state_list = State.objects.all()
    context = {'states': state_list}
    return render(request, 'reviews/reviews_index.html', context)

def state_detail(request, state=None):
    city_list = City.objects.order_by('city')
    context = {'cities': city_list}
    return render(request, 'reviews/state_detail.html', context)

def city_detail(request, state=None, city=None):
    school_list = School.objects.all()
    context = {'schools': school_list}
    return render(request, 'reviews/city_detail.html', context)
```

URLs

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include

from . import views 

app_name = 'reviews'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.reviews_index, name='reviews_index'),
    url(r'^(?P<state>[a-z]+)/$', views.state_detail, name='state_detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<state>[a-z]+)/(?P<city>[a-z]+)/$', views.city_detail, name='city_detail'),

]
```

However, when I try to create a link from the state_detail template to the city_detail template, I get this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /reviews/alabama/
Reverse for 'city_detail' with arguments '('', 'Auburn')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

This is how I am linking in the template:

```
{% block main_content %}
    <div class="content">
        <div class="row">
            {% if cities %}
            {% for city in cities %}
            <div class="medium-3 column">
                <a href="{% url 'city_detail' state.state city.city %}">{{ city.city }}</a>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Can someone please tell me that I am doing wrong and help me fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `state.state` is not defined in your `<a>` tag. I *think* altering it to `city.state` should do the trick

Comment: @gtlambert, I altered state.state in the <a> tag to city.state. But now I am getting this error: NoReverseMatch at /reviews/alabama/
Reverse for 'city_detail' with arguments '(<State: Alabama>, 'Auburn')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Comment: `city.state.state` will do it then, although that is pretty hacky. @alasdair solution below will be more robust

Comment: @gtlambert Actually, I think that your idea to use `city.state.state` is better. Using `state.state` works in the `state_detail` view, but if you are looping through cities from different states, then city.state.state` is better.

Comment: @Alasdair that makes sense. I just don't like the current naming conventions! Something like `city.state.slug` reads much better

Comment: @gtlambert I agree. It would be much better to choose variable names so that it is easy to tell the diffence between the `State` instance and e.g. `<State: Alabama>`, and the slug, e.g. `'alabama'`. Using `state` for both is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `city_detail` url pattern includes the `state.state`, so you need to include the state in the template context.

In your view, you can use `get_object_or_404` to fetch the state using the slug.

```
def state_detail(request, state=None):
    state = get_object_or_404(State, state=state)
    city_list = City.objects.filter(state=state).order_by('city')
    context = {'cities': `city_list`, 'state': state}
    return render(request, 'reviews/state_detail.html', context)
```

Note that I've changed city_list, so that it only displays cities in the state you are viewing.

It's not a great idea to use the same variable name `state` for the instance and the slug. It would be a good idea to rename one of them, e.g. to `state_obj` or `state_slug`. If you do this, you'll have to make sure you update your urls, views and templates to be consistent.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I appreciate your responses. However, now, I get a 404 error.

Comment: Which URL gives you the 404?

Comment: example.com/reviews/state

Comment: The line `state = get_object_or_404(State, state=state)` is fetching the state from the database with the slug from the url. If the state doesn't exist in the database, then a 404 is expected. You need to use a url like `example.com/reviews/alabama/` (assuming you have a state with slug `'alabama'` in the database).

Comment: I am using example.com/reviews/alabama. That is where I am getting the 404 error. All fifty states are in my database.

Comment: Are you sure that the slug is lowercase `alabama`? If the slug is `Alabama`, then you need to use the url `example.com/reviews/Alabama/`